# Is my Refactor not correct and clear?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Here is the original source, which contains a very common code pattern which I consider an anti-pattern or at best unnecessarily verbose:

```
private bool SymbolDevice;
. . .
    if((oemInfo.IndexOf("SYMBOL") > -1) || (oemInfo.IndexOf("MOTOROLA") > -1))
                            SymbolDevice = true;
                        else
                        {
                            SymbolDevice = false;
                        }
```

I would refactor it this way:

```
SymbolDevice = ((oemInfo.IndexOf("SYMBOL") > -1) || (oemInfo.IndexOf("MOTOROLA") > -1));
```

Resharper (version 2.0, the last version available for Visual Studio 2003 / .NET 1.1, which this project is) refactors it this way:

```
SymbolDevice = (oemInfo.IndexOf("SYMBOL") > -1) || (oemInfo.IndexOf("MOTOROLA") > -1) ? true : false;
```

I agree that Resharper's refactoring improves upon the legacy code, but is there any reason I would choose it over my version?

Comment: not really. Personal preference, eg, I'd generally write it as `SymbolDevice s = oemInfo.IndexOf("SYMBOL") > -1 || oemInfo.IndexOf("MOTOROLA") > -1`. With only two sides of the OR, explicit parentheses are unnecessary

Comment: Your (first) version is much better! You have to remember that R# is just a tool, so the outcome may not always be perfect.

Comment: You can use your code with no doubts.

Comment: I wonder whether R# will then propose to convert the code it generated to the first variant.

Comment: R#'s refactor of your existing code is too verbose.  You don't need a ternary operator to evaluate that line, at all.

Comment: +1 vote for your code over R#'s. I think twice about R#s refactorings these days - I'm sure it has jumped the shark.

Comment: I tried to post a different but similar question on CRSE, but it gave me a "Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above" and there is no error above...

Comment: The one that is now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077748/is-this-double-instantation-harmful-or-simply-unnecessary (posted here on SO fine). Maybe the problem was there was no "Resharper" tag there yet, but it didn't say so in the err msg (there was no err msg, except the one that pointed to the other phantom err msg). Strange that a "Code Review" site wouldn't have a Resharper tag; I would expect that to be one of the first tags extant.

Comment: Which version of R#? With a minimal similar example, I find R# 6.1 goes straight to your final version.

Comment: This is a .NET 1.1 project, and thus for this I have to use R#2; I do have the latest R# on my VS 2010 installation, and it is much more full-featured. Count me among the camp who finds R# to be the cat's meow; I couldn't, or at least wouldn't want to, code without it. If I was a coding genius, I wouldn't need it,  but...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would definitely choose your version. `x ? true : false` is equivalent to `x`.